# How to assign a certain numerical value to column number in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have code like this:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    If Range("A11") = "5" Then
        Range("C3:C6").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3:M6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
   End If
End Sub
```

I want to be able to enter a value in A11, which will alter the M value. In this case, entering 5 in A11, corresponds to value M in Destination:=Range. How can I create a sort of dynamic range with a small piece of code to indicate for example, that:

in A11, 5 = M, 6 = N, 7 = O, 8 = P, etc

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("C3:C6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3", Cells(6, 8 + [A11])), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I need to do. However, being such a beginner, what should I edit in the code, for example for a value of three, the code to paste the formulas in C3:F6?

Comment: @GlebPilipenko Sorry, didn't understand you. Не понял тебя :(

Comment: Спасибо, ты мне помог уже достаточно много :). Я твой код пастил в ВБА. В А11 вставил 3, и мои формулы копируются с С3:С6 до C3: K6.

Если 3 то мне надо было чтоб формулы копировались до F6. Как обозначить, как далеко формулы будут копироваться, смотря какую цифру вставляем в A11?

Comment: What about? `Range("C3:C6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3").Resize(4, [A11] + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault`

Comment: @sktneer That is EXACTLY, what I need. Appreciate that a lot, and thank you JohnyL.

Comment: If possible, would you be able to quickly explain the rational behind your formula?

Comment: @GlebPilipenko Oops! I forgot that I could use numbers directly :) sktneer's example is the way to go :)

Comment: @GlebPilipenko The columns are resized to the value you entered into `A11` plus one (`[A11]+1` part) and four rows down (`4` part). This is how `Resize` works. I also altered code for the original question.

Comment: @GlebPilipenko You're welcome! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @JohnyL Thanks for the assistance you provided to explain the logic I used. :)

Comment: @sktneer Not at all :)